# cannot write valid mount path for docker container in go

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to start a test container to test my database. I'm using test containers.
Here is a piece of code how I setup a container:

```
func createContainer(ctx context.Context) (testcontainers.Container, *pgxpool.Pool, string, error) {
var env = map[string]string{
        "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": DbPass,
        "POSTGRES_USER":     DbUser,
        "POSTGRES_DB":       DbName,
    }
    var port = "5432/tcp"

    // /Users/<path>:/<container path> 
    path := `/c/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/TgBotReminder/internal/db/postgresql/migration:/usr/app`

    req := testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
            Image:        "postgres:latest",
            ExposedPorts: []string{port},
            Env:          env,
            WaitingFor:   wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections"),
            VolumeMounts: map[string]string{"/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d": path},
            SkipReaper: true,
        },
        Started: true,
    }
    container, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        return container, nil, "", fmt.Errorf("unable to start container: %v", err)
    }
...
```

but I got an error from Docker: `failed to setup testunable to start container: failed to create container: Error response from daemon: create /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d: "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path`.

Sometimes this error looks like: `failed to setup testfailed to start container: failed to create container: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path:  '"c/Desktop/Folder/golang/TgBotReminder/internal/db/postgresql/migration/000001_init_schema.up"' mount path must be absolute`

I've tried many variations of my path such as:
`//c/Users/...`
`c/Users/...`
`/%cd%/Desktop/...`
`$HOME/Desktop/Folder/...`
but nothing helped me.

How to do it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Replace

```golang
VolumeMounts: map[string]string{"/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d": path},
```

with

```
BindMounts: map[string]string{"/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d": path},
```

---

#### Issue 1

> "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed.

It's important to know that there are [three types of mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/):

- **Volumes** are stored in a part of the host filesystem which is *managed by Docker* (`/var/lib/docker/volumes/` on Linux). Non-Docker processes should not modify this part of the filesystem. Volumes are the best way to persist data in Docker.
- **Bind mounts** may be stored *anywhere* on the host system. They may even be important system files or directories. Non-Docker processes on the Docker host or a Docker container can modify them at any time.
- **`tmpfs` mounts** are stored in the host system’s memory only, and are never written to the host system’s filesystem.

`VolumeMounts` is for specifying the volume mounts. As of `github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.12.0`, the value of an entry in `VolumeMounts` stores **the volume name**, which only allows `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`, that's why you see the error message. BTW, to see the error message above, your code must be something like this (note that `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` is the value instead of the key):

```golang
VolumeMounts: map[string]string{path: "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"},
```

---

#### Issue 2

> invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path:  '"c/Desktop/Folder/golang/TgBotReminder/internal/db/postgresql/migration/000001_init_schema.up"' mount path must be absolute

To see this error message, your code must be something like this:

```golang
VolumeMounts: map[string]string{`"/c/Desktop/Folder/golang/TgBotReminder/internal/db/postgresql/migration/000001_init_schema.up"`: "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"},
```

As of `github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.12.0`, the key of an entry in `VolumeMounts` stores the mount path. Since the mount path contains the double quotes (`"`), it's invalid. The docker daemon verifies the mount path first. That's why you see the error message.

---

#### Consider upgrading `github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go`

In release [v0.13.0](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/releases/tag/v0.13.0), `ContainerRequest.BindMounts` and `ContainerRequest.VolumeMounts` are replaced with `ContainerRequest.Mounts`. That's because "the map based data structure is somehow confusing. This change avoids confusion by introducing dedicated types for all components to get help by IDEs and the compiler". (see [PR#386](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/pull/386)).

After upgrading to `github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.21.0`, the bind mounts can be specified with:

```golang
Mounts: testcontainers.Mounts(
    testcontainers.BindMount(path, "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"),
),
```

Comment: thank you for detailed answer! i'll check your solutions tomorrow